# How to cross compile python wheel files for Raspberry pi and other devices

Tags: python, pip, cross-compiling

I want to install a few packages in RPI like pytorch , the compile time in it will be way too long. I don't wanna risk downloading unofficial ".whl" builds for the same

I have heard that cross compiling python packages is possible , but wasn't able to find any online resource guiding the same

How do I do it? Thanks in Advance

Comment: How you checked https://www.piwheels.org/packages.html already?